# Sqlite rowid > too many levels of trigger recursion, but trigger works fine?

Tags: sqlite, recursion

I havw a table: MYTABLE(ID int);

I am using this query to generate N numbers of rowids in mytable:

```
  create trigger mytrigger after insert on MYTABLE
  when new.id < 1000 
  begin
  insert into MYTABLE select max(id)+1 from MYTABLE;
  end;
  insert into MYTABLE values (1);
```

It works fine, sqlite would generate me a rowid from 1 to 1000.

But when I subsitute:

```
when new.id < 1000
```

with larger number like:

```
when new.id < 10000000
```

I receive an error: **too many levels of trigger recursion**

Now my question is, what's the point of a trigger if it can not handle at least one million options? Is there any way to solve that or should i just go and insert each row by myself:)

Comment: Triggers are not meant to have an arbitrary level of recursion. Why must it be a trigger anyway?

Comment: Well, I thought it might be the simplest solution, but of course i am open for everything.

Comment: The simples solution to *what*? What kind of problem are you solving by that trigger?

Comment: I am just exploring sqlite, comparing possabilities with excel and so on. I thought trigger might be the useful solution, however it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers are not meant to have an arbitrary level of recursion.

The mechanism for arbitrary recursions are [recursive common table expressions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(id)
WITH RECURSIVE n(i) AS (
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i + 1 FROM n WHERE i < 1000
)
SELECT i FROM n;
```

Comment: Lol, very simple, very great. Thank you very much.